# Conditional replace in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I'd like do use vim search-and-replace to replace all " with ' and vice-versa. Is there a way to achieve this in one step? I'm thinking of something like this:

```
:s/\("\|'\)/\1=="?':"/
```

Where of course the `\1=="?':"`-part is something that works in vim.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's a case for `:help sub-replace-special`:

```
:s/["']/\=submatch(0) == '"' ? "'" : '"'/g
```

This matches any of the two quotes (in a simpler way with `[...]`), and then uses the ternary operator to turn each quote into its opposite. (For more complex cases, you could use Dictionary lookups.)

Comment: Can the matched patterns `\1`, `\2`, ... be used in the substituting expressions? I tried, but backslashes are inserted literally.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: Yes, via `submatch(1)` etc.; the literal `\1` doesn't work here.

Comment: Suppose I want to substitute `m1`, `m2`, `m3` and so on with `11`, `21`, `31` and `p1`, `p2`, `p3` and so on with `12`, `22`, `32`. I'd go with `:s/\([mp]\)\(.\)/\=submatch(1) == 'm' ? '???' : '???'`, but I don't understand what the two alternative substitution strings (`???`) should be.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis: `:s/\([mp]\)\(.\)/\=submatch(2) . (submatch(1) == 'm' ? '1' : '2')/g`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! My error was to try to use `submatch` in the quotes of the `= ? :` construct.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (that's more suited to scripting) is to use the built-in `tr()` function. To apply it on the buffer, `getline()` / `setline()` is used:

```
:call setline('.', tr(getline('.'), "'\"", "\"'"))
```

Answer (score 3):

power of unix tools ;)

`:%!tr "'\"" "\"'"`

Answer (score 2):

You can do so easily by using the [***abolish.vim***](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin.

*Abolish.vim* has a `:Subvert` command which gives you a different approach to searching and replacing in its own little DSL.

```
:%S/{\",'}/{',\"}/g
```

This plugin has received the special honour of having a three-part screencast on Vimcasts.org
dedicated to it: [one](http://vimcasts.org/e/47), [two](http://vimcasts.org/e/48),
[three](http://vimcasts.org/e/49).

Comment: What's with the escaping of `\"`; that's highly unintuitive?! (I get an `E64` when I remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the laziest/easiest way:

```
  :%s/'/__/g | %s/"/'/g | %s/__/"/g
```

Three basic steps combined into one line:

1. convert `'` to `__`   (or something random)
2. convert `"` to `'`
3. convert  `__` to `"`

Then combine them with the `|` symbol.

I'm sure some vim wizards will have a better solution, but that worked for me.

Comment: I thought about that, and I could surely do it, but vim is mighty and I'm just curious, if there is a one-step-solution for this problem ;-)

Comment: Vim is mighty. I'm sure people will have something even easier.