# Conditional replacement using regex in atom editor

Tags: regex, replace, find, conditional-statements, atom-editor

I wanted to replace text based on 1 digit code all at once

08-**m**

08-**o**

into

08_**may**

08_**october**

what I am trying to do is replace "m" into "may","o" into "October" all these at once,I am trying to put them in conditional replacement in atom editor

capturing using
08-(\w)

replacing expression
08-(?(\w="m")may|?(\w="o")october)

its not working and I dont know why

I am a beginner in regex,not finding what I am looking for anywhere,pardon me if you find it really dumb.Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use regex in replacement patterns. To replace with different values, you can only use Notepad++.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as a vim user, disagree your "you can only use Notepad++" comment. ^_^

Comment: @Kent Ok, [Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17337979/3832970) and [Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161309/3832970). Though in Vim, it looks like a whole separate  language already.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes vim regex has some difference from PCRE, however IMO, in some cases, it is more powerful than PCRE.

Comment: @Kent I would not compare it to PCRE, they are rather different. If you ask me, I'd call Vim regex a "language isolate". Ah, and if you mentioned PCRE because I mentioned Notepad++, just FYI that NPP uses Boost regex library, not PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

### did you try **Find in Project**?

Use shortcut`ctrl`+`shift`+`f` then complete `Find in project` with **08-m** and `Replace in project` with **08_may**. Complete the `File/directory` input then click on `Replace All`.

Do the same for 08-o and do not hesitate to first click on `Find All` to be sure not to make mistakes.

This is not really a regex answer but can be usefull if your aim is the solution and not the method.